# Creating VM with Azure CLI

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, command-line-interface

I'm posting to see if someone can point me in the right direction. I've been trying to get this working for a few days now and I'm at a dead end.

I have tried to remove `"` around the variables and remove variables completely. I have tried to run this in Azure Cloud Shell, WSL, and PowerShell as a `.ps1` script. However, I continue to get the same type of errors.

[Here](https://github.com/hoxflank/scripts-shared/blob/master/new-machine.sh) is the script.

Here is the error I am getting.

> validation error: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the
>   following pattern: '^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'. ' not recognized. ' not found. Check the spelling and casing and
>   try again.

If I run a one liner with out variables I get this error.

> az vm create: error: local variable 'images' referenced before
>   assignment

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ps: `https://codepad.co/` is great fro sharing snippets

Comment: I have opened a Microsoft Support case regarding this issue also. I will update if there are able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

So for the first error, looks like the create VM is initiating to fast to recognize the new resource group.

For the image you need to use the full URN `MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter:latest`

[image]

Comment: Looks like you might have used `images` instead of `image` when you actual ran script.

Comment: Thanks @Hannel for you suggestion. I was using the URN alias based on the output of "az vm create -h" https://imgur.com/6Jm5U1o

Comment: Changing to the full URN gets this error:

' failed for an error 'Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/eastus2%0D/publishers/MicrosoftWindowsServer/artifacttypes/vmimage/offers/WindowsServer/skus/2016-Datacenter/versions/latest%0D?api-version=2019-03-01'. Configuring plan settings will be skipped
Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'.

Comment: You need to make sure you have all you variables and syntax right. https://i.imgur.com/WST92cg.png

Comment: Thanks @Hannel for the help. I did have some syntax issues. I have correct those issues and I'm not able to run each line manually to create a vm. However, there still seems to be a issue when running the script as a .ps1 or .sh file. Could just be limitation of Azure CLI?

Comment: .ps1 error: https://i.imgur.com/GspospG.png
.sh error https://i.imgur.com/U7nuiSs.png

Comment: The issue is not an Azure issue or limitation of CLI. To interact with CLI you must be login to an account and scripting works fine. 
https://i.imgur.com/su84FFw.png script: https://codepad.co/snippet/new-machine

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a bash script and the variable definition is different between Windows and Linux. So I suggest you run the script in the Azure Cloud Shell with bash mode or the WSL when it's a bash script.

Second, the error shows the resource group name does not meet the [Naming rules and restrictions for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/resource-naming), you need to read the document to check if the group name is right.

Comment: I have confirmed that the resource group naming is good. I have also tried running this in Azure Shell. This is the error I am getting.
https://i.imgur.com/eoaBn08.png

Comment: @roddknocker What is the group name you had used?

Comment: @roddknocker If the answer is helpful for you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found out that the issue was. It was how VS Code formats bash scripts. I'm not exactly sure how VS Code is formatting but I think it might have something to do with ASCII. I recreated the script in Azure CLI with nano and it runs fine as a bash shell script. Thanks everyone for your help.